# PHP - FETCH THE "X-ERROR-XXX" response headers with CURL

Tags: php, curl

SO PHP Does have a curl interface where I can connect, post, and download stuff.
I can Also

1. Get response headers via `CURLOPT-HEADER` and other options set to true.
2. Get the response as an array, with `curl_getinfo`

But HOW do I fetch the `X-XYZ` response headers?

for example, An API might send me info about whether a key is valid/invalid/Already Used

via

- `X-ERROR`
- `X-ERROR-CODE`

Unfortunately, I have NO way of fetching these headers/Can't Find one.

I Can set the `CURLOPT_HEADER` to `TRUE`, and then execute CURL,

But, I would need duplicate requests/posts with the same access token

And the nature of the API, restricts the use of a token to a SINGLE use.

For those who might suggest `curlopt_header`, please note

> I use the token once, with that option set to true, and I exhaust the API token.

I can not reuse the token, to make the actual request next.

IF PHP CURL has an option, that includes these X-XYZ headers in the response of a curl_getinfo, then, such a feature would be useful

#### SOLUTION:

@billynoah wrote an absolute gem. See below.You can either use his function that writes back headers, or write your own. BUT,

> ## TL;DR
>
> ### USE
>
> `curl_setopt(<your-curl-handle>, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, <your-custom-header-collector-function>);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this function to get and parse the headers from a curl response - here's an example:

```
$headers = array();
$url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43535006/php-fetch-the-x-error-xxx-response-headers-with-curl';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, 'readHeader');
$result = curl_exec($curl);
print_r($headers);
curl_close($curl);

function readHeader($ch, $header) {
    global $headers;
    if (trim($header)) {
        $parts = explode(':',$header,2);
        $parts = array_map('trim',$parts);
        if (count($parts) == 2) {
            $headers[$parts[0]] = $parts[1];
        } else if (!isset($headers['http_code'])) {
            $headers['http_code'] = trim($header);
        } else {
            $headers[] = trim($header);
        }   
    }   
    return strlen($header);
}
```

**RESPONSE:**

```
Array
(
    [http_code] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [Content-Type] => text/html; charset=utf-8
    [X-Frame-Options] => SAMEORIGIN
    [X-Request-Guid] => 9df57b2d-df0a-4902-93f6-1dca0faab9d5
    [Content-Length] => 73067
    [Accept-Ranges] => bytes
    [Date] => Fri, 21 Apr 2017 06:33:33 GMT
    [Via] => 1.1 varnish
    [Age] => 0
    [Connection] => keep-alive
    [X-Served-By] => cache-jfk8122-JFK
    [X-Cache] => MISS
    [X-Cache-Hits] => 0
    [X-Timer] => S1492756414.633607,VS0,VE15
    [Vary] => Fastly-SSL
    [X-DNS-Prefetch-Control] => off
    [Set-Cookie] => prov=3cecd5a6-44ca-d63a-439e-921bc200d61d; domain=.stackoverflow.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
    [Cache-Control] => private
)
```

As you can see all `X-` headers are present in the resulting array and we are able to view them in one shot along with the response.

Comment: ! Thanks for the quick response. I am trying this now. Will let you know cheers :)